# Is it possible to update a table inside a select statement using FMDatabaseQueue in FMDB?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

I am changing my old FMDB to new version and it makes lot of issues in database operations.I want to update a table inside a select query. Now using latest version of FMDB I cannot update the table. It will always produce an error "Unknown error calling sqlite3_step (5: database is locked) eu" and stuck the application.How can I do it with FMDatabaseQueue class.Anyone please help me.Thanks in advance.